# Css for menu issue, don't know how to centre them

Tags: css, css-position

I've got a problem, I've created a css menu on a "service" page, which has no support, and I have no idea how to correct this issue.

So I need your guys help, here's part of the css code (had to remove the first 40 lines of comments)

This menu is presented to the left, but I need it to be centered, anybody knows how?

```
.menuu{margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:30px; width:100%; display:block; background:url("//wearenotalone.se/images/topMenuImages.png") repeat-x;}

.menuu li{padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; display:inline;}

.menuu li a{float:left; padding-left:15px; display:block; color:rgb(255,255,255); text-decoration:none; font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; cursor:pointer; background:url("//wearenotalone.se/images/topMenuImages.png") 0px -30px no-repeat; outline:none;}

.menuu li a span{line-height:30px; float:left; display:block; padding-right:15px; background:url("//wearenotalone.se/images/topMenuImages.png") 100% -30px no-repeat;}

.menuu li a:hover{background-position:0px -60px; color:rgb(255,255,255);}
.menuu li a:hover span{background-position:100% -60px;}

.menuu li a.active, 
.menuu li a.active:hover{line-height:30px; font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:url("//wearenotalone.se/images/topMenuImages.png") 0px -90px no-repeat; color:rgb(255,255,255);}

.menuu li a.active span, .menuu li a.active:hover span{background:url("//wearenotalone.se/images/topMenuImages.png") 100% -90px no-repeat;}
```

Yeah, sorry, that above is the css,
This is how I call it:

```
<ul class="menuu">
  <li><a href="https://wearenotalone.se" ><span>Home</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

Well, that only displays one "button" in the menu, but it's only to add as many you want..
(Complete menu from [www.cssmenubuilder.com](http://www.cssmenubuilder.com))

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Could you provide some of the html code or create a code snippet. It would make it much easier to answer the question

Comment: Have you tried to use `display: flex` for your menu ?

Comment: The flex did work little, it got centered, but also did the spaces, so now there are large empty spaces between the 'buttons"

Answer (score 0):

@j-printemps display: flex is working great.